# Summarize and pivot data in dataset with dynamic values with Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We have a dataset with the following format in Azure Data Explorer, where the timestamp is on a millisecond level and data is streaming in in large amounts.

| sensorid | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| valve1 | 24-03-2021 | 123 |
| valve1 | 23-03-2021 | 234 |
| cylinderspeed | 23-03-2021 | 1.2 |
| productcode | 23-03-2021 | abc |
| productcode | 24-03-2021 | def |

In the above data, the valve1 and cyliderspeed sensors would report multiple time per second but the productcode would be reported when the production line starts to produce another product.

With this Kusto query we can get out all numeric values into a table that can be imported into Excel or PowerBi

```
FactoryData
| where sourcetimestamp > ago(1h)
| summarize average=avg(todouble(value)) by bin(timestamp, 1s), sensorid
| evaluate pivot(sensorid, any(average))
```

I would like to change this query so that the summarization is done on the average, like above, if the value is a number, but on a string if not a number.

Update:
The outcome that I'm interested in is a table that looks like this, where the sensorid values have been pivoted to columns

| timestamp | valve1 | cylinderspeed | productcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23-03-2021 | 123 | 1,2 | abc |
| 24-mars | 234 |  | def |

This is easily achieved for numeric data with the query shown above. I can also do something like this:

```
FactoryData
| where sourcetimestamp > ago(1h)
| summarize binvalue=any(value) by bin(sourcetimestamp, 1s), sensorid
| evaluate pivot(sensorid, any(binvalue))
```

This will produce the wanted result, but if a sensor has multiple numeric values in a one-second bin, this will take *any* one of them and not calculate an average.

So the questions is, that how can I change the above query so that for numeric sensors, binvalue will be an average, and for string sensors it will be any value in the bin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the following line:
`| summarize average=iif(value>0, avg(todouble(value)), any(value)) by bin(timestamp, 1s), sensorid`

You're trying to check if `value>0`, but this doesn't work in `summarize` as `summarize` is done on all values (not to mention that it won't work as `value` is of type `string`.

Or are you saying that the strings in the `value` column may represent numbers for some of the records, so you want to find out (per `sensorId`) the average of the numbers, and take any non-numeric value?

If so, this is your way to go:

```
FactoryData
| where sourcetimestamp > ago(1h)
| extend ValueAsDouble = todouble(value)
| extend ValueAsString = iff(isnull(ValueAsDouble), value, "N/A")
| summarize avg(ValueAsDouble), make_set(ValueAsString, 2) by sensorId
| mv-expand set_ValueAsString
| where set_ValueAsString != "N/A"
| summarize any(avg_ValueAsDouble), any(set_ValueAsString) by sensorId
```

The the best way would be to separate numeric and non-numeric values into different columns in ingestion, it would make the query easier to read and also much more efficient.